# Minimizing Meyers' singleton overhead

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, singleton, static-initialization

Meyers singleton, s. t.:

```cpp
Foo& getSingleton() {
    static Foo singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

Is known to be:

- Thread-safe.
- Have a branch(es?) inside.

And it also happens to be the easiest way to avoid static initialization order fiasco.

But, if I'm executing in single-threaded environment, its thread-safety (which can't be disabled via default language means) might be critical to performance.

What are the ways industry uses to get rid of extra atomic flag for Meyers singleton and minimize branches.

Comment: one rather popular way is to not use a singleton in the first place.

Comment: Another way is to get away from the obsession with maximising performance (which usually results in premature optimisation - spending time optimising performance even if it is not actually necessary) and instead realise that it is predictability of performance that usually matters most.     If you do that, performance criteria usually amount to having sensible upper and lower bounds for the worst case execution time for relevant sequences of operations, and designing the system as a whole (hardware, etc) to meet those and provide suitable margins for expansion.

Comment: what you refer to as overhead, is the solution to both, thread-safety, and static initialization order. If you can compromise on both, you dont need a meyers singleton. I always get confused when ppl call it "overhead" when they refer to just what something is supposed to do. (With some exaggeration) its like saying `a + b` has the *overhead* of adding two numbers.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I need static local storage object but I don't need thread-safety therefore I don't want to pay for it

Comment: The overhead is likely a check of a lock-free atomic if it's not optimized away. If you find this slowing down things too much, you can probably make local references `auto& the_foo = getSingleton(); /* use the_foo in this function */`

Comment: If you need a solution for the static initialization then the solution comes together with thread safety. I mean, probably one could design something that helps with static initialization but is not thread safe, but why would you when there is something that helps with both?

Comment: Exactly how much is it slowing down the access to the instance compared to if you just create a "normal" instance?

Comment: If it "might be critical to performance" it is a premature optimization.

Comment: The overhead is no more than one failed atomic exchange per `get_instance` call. Not big of a deal. In functions that use it multiple times, cach the returned object within a reference to minimize that marginal overhead.

Comment: If you do not need thread safety, then you can use a global pointer variable. When the pointer is null, you can create Foo using a Meyers singleton. When the pointer is not null, there is nothing to pay except the conditional check, but conditionals are very cheap when they are correctly predicted, like 1 cycles on recent mainstream CPUs. This is a singleton, so the condition is always true when the initialization is done. This is the price to pay for the dynamic instantiation (same for the pointer which can be fetched speculatively in parallel anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For gcc, clang, and msvc there are specific commandline options to turn off thread safety for static variables [1][2][3].

That beeing said, before using these flags (basically switching to non-C++-standard-mode) one should have carefully measured and identified the synchronization on the singleton as a hotspot optimization opportunity.

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno-threadsafe-statics 
[2] https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fthreadsafe-statics 
[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization

Comment: Re: “switching to non-C++-standard-mode” — in a single-threaded application removing thread safety overhead conforms to the standard. The program will do what it’s supposed to do, and the program cannot detect that the checks aren’t there.

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers have options to compile with or without threads -- compiling without threads should generate a version which doesn't add any thread dependent overhead. More generally, however, I would expect the thread overhead to be negligible in a single threaded program -- acquiring an uncontested mutex normally only costs a single access to an atomic bool -- not the end of the world. I wouldn't worry about it until the profiler shows it to be a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

A modern Meyers singleton does not need to require **any** atomic, fence or locking operations and can still be thread safe once the singleton had been created. This means the normal path (e.g. not the first time the thread encounters the static) is very very fast.

On MSVC x64 for example, a Meyers singleton for initialisation check requires 5 normal loads and a compare (+normal function overhead).

It does this by using TLS instead of atomics -> basically it has a table of epochs per thread and knows the "high watermark" of each thread, and then it can do a normal compare of that watermark with a value which represents when the static was created, in order to know whether it needs to do more complex multi-threaded or atomic work (which it only needs to do at most once per thread).

See lines 510 -> 516
https://godbolt.org/z/caGr6oqxa

The compare also will be well predicted as it's always true after the first call for each thread. So in a way there's no atomic operations and no branches with any real cost. Just a handful of loads.

You really do not have to worry about the cost of singletons.

You may want to check out whether your compiler supports this feature.

But obviously, if you are worried then run some performance tests.